# Array column in dataframe as input for classification models

Tags: regression, numpy, logistic

Please consider the following dataframe:

[image]

My challenge is with the column 'geometry_coordnates'.

I've got a column 'geometry_coordnates' that is an array of numbers. It can be a representation of a line or a polygon.

If it is a line, the size of the array is 4. If it is a polygon, the array size can be a minimum of 3 numbers and as big as 30 - or more.

What's your thoughts on how to inform this column to the ML model? Using the array column directly does not work, it causes for example the Logistic Regression model to throw an exception.

Any suggestions? Transform the array column into something else for example?

Thanks